# Problems with running repo command on Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Pipeline on Jenkins that cloning a Gerrit repo using with an xml file.

So when I try on Jenkins Ubuntu server CLI, command runs fine.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/test/test-manifest.git -m dev-test.xml
```

After I run the command, it asks me Github credentials form the prompt.

I want to use same command on Jenkinsfile, tried with different syntaxes but didn't worked. I'm adding last Jenkinsfile and the errors below.

Errors from Jenkins Pipeline console:

```
Cloning repo..
[Pipeline] sh
+ repo init -u https://github.com/test/test-manifest.git -m dev-test.xml

... A new version of repo (2.40) is available.
... New version is available at: /home/test/workspace/Test/.repo/repo/repo
... The launcher is run from: /usr/bin/repo
!!! The launcher is not writable.  Please talk to your sysadmin or distro
!!! to get an update installed.

fatal: cannot obtain manifest https://github.com/test/test-manifest.git
================================================================================
Repo command failed: UpdateManifestError
    Unable to sync manifest dev-test.xml
repo: reusing existing repo client checkout in /home/test/workspace/Test

manifests:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
manifests: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ubuntu-server' }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Cloning repo..'
                        sh 'repo init -u https://github.com/test/test-manifest.git -m dev-test.xml'
            }
        }
   }
```

I tried to add credentials code like below but still doesn't work.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxx-xxxx-yyyy-yyyyy-xxxxxxxxxx', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
```

How can I run that "repo init" command successfully from Jenkinsfile=